# How to remove these line shading artifacts?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

[image]

How do I remove these ugly shading lines? I have tried selecting the loop and using inset. I have tried subdivision surface. I have tried edge split modifier. Nothing works.  Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You have to clean up your geometry by removing some of the egde loops in case you'd like to have it more smooth using a subdiv modifier. Start of by converting the triangles to quads, then remove all unnecessary loops.

Comment: As brockmann said, *Subdivision* requires quad faces to work properly. You'll have to manually retopologize, or use the new [Remesh tools](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-81/#remeshing)

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything. Make same sphere like you did. Don't divide it into triangles. Use proportional editing tool (shortcut "O") for every change with vertices. Go right click => SHADE SMOOTH. Add subdivision surface.